# VBA to automate a selected chart .placement property to xlmove (Move but don't size"

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am working on getting a VBA code to automatically set a chartArea object to move but don't size with cells.
The object that I have selected is a ChartArea so I think I need to refer to it's parent but this still is not getting me anywhere. I have searched and tried a few variations but any help would be appreciated!

I can loop through all of the  charts using:

```
  For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    cht.Placement = PropertyOption
  Next cht
```

But I want to apply this sub to another function that changes other aspects of the chart.

```vb
Sub aMOOOve()

    Dim selectedChart As ChartObject
    Dim chartArea As chartArea
    Dim parentChart As ChartObject
    
    ' Check if a chart is selected
    If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then
        ' Get the parent chart area
        Set chartArea = Selection
        
        ' Change the position to 2 (xlMove)
        Set parentChart = chartArea.Parent
        parentChart.Chart.Placement = xlMove
        
        ' Optional: Refresh the chart to see the changes
        parentChart.Chart.Refresh
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a chart first.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

This is returning a compile error: Method or data member not found but other variations have had different errors.

Answer (score 0):

- The relation of related objects: ChartObject >> Chart >> ChartArea
- `Placement` is a property of `ChartObject`

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ChartObject.Placement property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.placement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm494088)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub aMOOOve()
    Dim selectedChart As ChartObject
    Dim crtArea As chartArea
    Dim parentChart As Chart
    Dim crtObject As ChartObject
    ' Check if a chart is selected
    If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then
        ' Get the parent chart area
        Set crtArea = Selection
        Set parentChart = crtArea.Parent
        Set crtObject = parentChart.Parent
        ' Change the position to 2 (xlMove)
        crtObject.Placement = xlMove
        crtObject.Chart.Refresh
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a chart first.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```